# Rename a file in linux which has date appended to it

Tags: linux, bash, rename

There is a single file in a folder which has date and time appended to it. I would like to rename it to something else so that I can access it easily. I know the starting word of this file name. Is they there a way I can rename this (using wildcard or something)? . Can't use Tab since I am trying to write a script to automate something.

Also, I would like to access the lexicographical last element and rename it if there are multiple files.

Comment: You can consider soft linking to it rather than renaming it.

Comment: You can post the starting name as you said in the OP and what would you like to rename it to (and) also the date format ?

Comment: Lets say it is Abc_10Jun2016_04_02_14 and I would like to rename it to Abc_latest. Have added some more details in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the last changed file in a directory? Which matches a pattern?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "prefix*" \
  -printf "%TY%Tm%TdTH%TM %p\n" | sort -nr | read -r _ file

printf "%s" "$file"
```

Assuming no filename contains newlines. And that you actually just want to get the last changed file in a directory.

Alternative you can sort do something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "prefix*" | sort -nr -t- -k2
```

Which will sort files like this:

```
prefix-2016-05-05
prefix-2016-06-05
prefix-2016-04-08
```

To

```
prefix-2016-06-05
prefix-2016-05-05
prefix-2016-04-08
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of the file is `bob_2016-06-10_06:00:00.txt` you could do this:

```
mv *_20[0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].txt commmonname.txt
```

Comment: Hi Michael,
Have added some more details in question. If there are multiple files in folder, I want to access the lexicographic last element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **rename** with a regexp. The syntax is:

```
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

So, given the following files:

```
coda@pong:/tmp/kk$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--  1 coda coda     0 Jun 10 13:28 aaaa-2016-01-01.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 coda coda     0 Jun 10 13:28 aaaa-2016-01-02.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 coda coda     0 Jun 10 13:28 aaaa-2016-01-03.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 coda coda     0 Jun 10 13:28 aaaa-2016-01-04.txt
```

You can rename them this way:

```
coda@pong:/tmp/kk$ rename -v 's/aaaa/xxxx/' *.txt
aaaa-2016-01-01.txt renamed as xxxx-2016-01-01.txt
aaaa-2016-01-02.txt renamed as xxxx-2016-01-02.txt
aaaa-2016-01-03.txt renamed as xxxx-2016-01-03.txt
aaaa-2016-01-04.txt renamed as xxxx-2016-01-04.txt
```

If you want to keep track of the lexicographical last element, I would use something like this in the script:

```
ln -sf `ls | tail -n1` latest
```

Since ls sorts by name by default, you will always have a link to your lexicographical last element:

```
coda@pong:/tmp/kk$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 coda coda  0 Jun 10 13:28 xxxx-2016-01-01.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 coda coda  0 Jun 10 13:28 xxxx-2016-01-02.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 coda coda  0 Jun 10 13:28 xxxx-2016-01-03.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 coda coda  0 Jun 10 13:28 xxxx-2016-01-04.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 coda coda 19 Jun 10 13:59 latest -> xxxx-2016-01-04.txt
```

Comment: Note this is not to be confused with `rename` from `util-linux`. This command is sometimes also called `perl-rename`

Comment: I added some more details in question. If there are multiple files, is there a way to access lexicographic last file